# Why does the option --add_extra_groups in adduser contain underscore rather than hyphen word delimiters?

Tags: history, options

### Premise

Most of the long-form options in the various *nix tools use hyphens as word separators.

### Examples

from `man tr`:

```
 --squeeze-repeats
 --truncate-set1
```

from `man sudo`:

```
--preserve-env
--set-home
--non-interactive
```

Many more examples could be given.

### Question

Why does the option `--add_extra_groups` in `adduser` contain underscore rather than hyphen word delimiters? Even the other long-form options in `adduser` use hyphens:

```
SYNOPSIS
     adduser  [options] [--no-create-home] [--disabled-password] [--disabled-login] 
     [--add_extra_groups] [--encrypt-home] user
```

Is this just a typo that has become normalized over time, or is there some other explanation?

Comment: I suspect it’s a typo, but you’d have to ask Stephen Gran, [the author of the feature](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/adduser/-/commit/83a0d57).

Answer (score 0):

It's a typo, even if the option works anyway.

By standard, hyphens should be used to separate words, even if sometimes one can find underscores.
For instance, here's what *The GNU C Library Reference Manual* [says about long options](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argument-Syntax.html):

> Long options consist of `--` followed by a name made of alphanumeric characters and dashes. Option names are typically one to three words long, with hyphens to separate words.